# PHP: Translate relative img src urls to absolute

Tags: php, html, url, image, absolute-path

I have fetched an HTML page using cURL into a string and loaded it up in a DOMDocument. There I can get all the img tags and their source attributes. My problem now is... how can I make these URLs absolute?

The list of URLs can contain all kinds of variants, for example:

- `foobar.jpg`
- `http://example.com/foobar.jpg`
- `/foobar.jpg`
- `../foobar.jpg`
- `folder/foobar.jpg`

If the HTML is fetched from an arbitrary URL, what is a safe way of converting these image URLs into absolute ones? Is there a way you can take the base tag into consideration too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is great PHP example how to do this.

```
function rel2abs($rel, $base) { 
// something
}
```

More good examples:

- [How to convert a relative URL to an absolute URL](http://nadeausoftware.com/node/79)
- [How to parse and build URLs](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/05/php_tip_how_parse_and_build_urls)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a handy function found on [this page](http://nashruddin.com/PHP_Script_for_Converting_Relative_to_Absolute_URL) :

```
function absUrl($rel, $base) {
    if (parse_url($rel, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != '') return $rel;
    if ($rel[0]=='#' || $rel[0]=='?') return $base.$rel;
    extract(parse_url($base));
    $path = preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', '', $path);
    if ($rel[0] == '/') $path = '';
    $abs = "$host$path/$rel"; 
    $re = array('#(/\.?/)#', '#/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/\.\./#');
    for($n=1; $n>0; $abs=preg_replace($re, '/', $abs, -1, $n)) {}   
    return $scheme.'://'.$abs;
}
```

`$rel` is your relative path and `$base` is your base URL.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it was necessary. I found this actually in our company's repository.